# How to integrate gerrit to jira

Tags: jira, gerrit

I am currently setting up my own Gerrit server (version: gerrit-3.8.0.war)
and I am also using Jira (https://xxxx.atlassian.com).
Jira provides a plugin named "GITHUB FOR JIRA" that allows you to trace commits in each JIRA issue ticket.
I need this functionality on my Gerrit server.
My goal is to track these commits in my JIRA issue ticket whenever I push to my Gerrit repository.

I discovered a plugin named "its-jira" on the Google Gerrit plugin site
([its-jira plugin link](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/admin/repos/plugins%2Fits-jira)).
I built and applied this plugin to my Gerrit server without any errors or problems.
However, the integration still isn't working.

Here's my Gerrit configuration for JIRA:

```
[its-jira] 
url = https://xxxx/atlassian.net 
username = xxxxx@xxxx.com 
connectTimeout = 120000 ms 
readTimeout = 30000 ms 

[commentlink "its-jira"] 
match = ([A-Z]+-[0-9]+) 
html = <a href=\"https://xxxx.atlassian.net//browse/$1\">$1</a> 

[plugin "its-jira"] 
association = MANDATORY
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config worked.
But gerrit upgrade the commentlink rule in 3.8, so I guess it's what you are facing.
Please check the following commit. There's a command show how to change your config.

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/c/gerrit/+/351515/10/tools/migration/html_to_link_commentlink.md#38